# Can the Supreme Court define what civil liberties Americans enjoy?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court

Can the Supreme Court define what civil liberties Americans enjoy? Or, the Court can use the rulings only against infringing of civil right (which are different from civil liberties)?

Comment: Veto is the power of the president not the supreme court.

Comment: ...and I'm not sure how a veto would define anything.

Comment: @DA. - see my edit to user1873's answer (if you assume OP mis-spoke about "veto")

Comment: @DVK - The Supreme Court still does not use the veto they use their judicial powers to review rulings.  They can only confirm or reject a lower courts ruling and then either substitute their own ruling or return the case to the original court.

Comment: @Chad - they can also write an opinion which (as was the case with Miranda) is essencially a rule in and out of itself.

Comment: @DVK - Their opinion is an interpretation of the law...  it is not a dictation of new law... even if it seemingly has that effect.

Comment: @Chad - either of those wordings fall under "define what civil liberties Americans enjoy" despite technical legal difference between them

Comment: @DVK - But that is not using Veto power...  Answer the question asked or ask your own question...

Comment: ROFL So you edit the question to fit your answer instead of asking your own question this SE is becoming a joke...

Answer (score 1):

Using te power of judicial review, the supreme court can define what civil liberties citizens and non-citizens are entitled to. The courts can also determine when a persons civil-rights were violated when they were discriminated against. [Find Law](http://civilrights.findlaw.com/civil-rights-overview/civil-rights-vs-civil-liberties.html) has a nice synopsis:

> It is important to note the difference between "civil rights" and "civil liberties." The legal area known as "civil rights" has traditionally revolved around the basic right to be free from unequal treatment based on certain protected characteristics (race, gender, disability, etc.) in settings such as employment and housing. "Civil liberties" concern basic rights and freedoms that are guaranteed -- either explicitly identified in the Bill of Rights and the Constitution, or interpreted through the years by courts and lawmakers. [...]
>
> One way to consider the difference between "civil rights" and "civil liberties" is to look at 1) what right is affected, and 2) whose right is affected. For example, as an employee, you do not have the legal right to a promotion, mainly because getting a promotion is not a guaranteed "civil liberty." But, as a female employee you do have the legal right to be free from discrimination in being considered for that promotion

---

A specific example is the iconic *[Miranda Warning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_warning)*:

> The concept of "Miranda rights" was enshrined in U.S. law following the 1966 Miranda v. Arizona Supreme Court decision, which found that the Fifth and Sixth Amendment rights of Ernesto Arturo Miranda had been violated during his arrest and trial for domestic violence. (Miranda was subsequently retried and convicted.)
>
> ... The ruling states:
>
> > ...The person in custody must, prior to interrogation, be clearly informed that he/she has the right to remain silent, and that anything the person says will be used against that person in court; the person must be clearly informed that he/she has the right to consult with an attorney and to have that attorney present during questioning, and that, if he/she is indigent, an attorney will be provided at no cost to represent him/her.

Note that the court very explicitly created a well-defined civil liberty (being informed of your rights prior to interrogation) where one didn't practically exist before, by interpreting existing law.

---

Another example would be a [civil liberty to same-sex marriage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Proposition_8). While the SCOTUS ruled on this, their ruling was merely a procedural one over jurisdiction, so the actual "creation of civil liberty" was really done at the circuit court level:

> After the California Supreme Court upheld the voter initiative, a suit, Perry v. Schwarzenegger (later Hollingsworth v. Perry), was filed in a Federal District Court in San Francisco. On August 4, 2010, U.S. District Chief Judge Vaughn Walker overturned Proposition 8, stating it is "...**unconstitutional under the Due Process Clause because no compelling state interest justifies denying same-sex couples the fundamental right to marry.**"[200] The court also determined that "Proposition 8 violated the Equal Protection Clause because there is no rational basis for limiting the designation of 'marriage' to opposite-sex couples."

Comment: The court interprets the laws to determine when someones civil liberties have been violated.  It does not say what rights and liberties the citizens are entitled too.  That comes from the consititution or laws passed by congress.

Comment: The courts are interpreting the laws...  they are not defining them like a law would as you say above.

Comment: @user1873 This isn't the place to have a political discussion.

Comment: @Chad - "Miranda" ruling says you're wrong. Before the court's ruling, people didn't enjoy the civil liberty of being read their Miranda - despite having had civil right to it.

Comment: @DVK - I think you are misunderstanding that ruling... maybe it would make a good question to ask

Comment: @Chad - please clarify re: misunderstanding? The ruling was that the suspect has a right to be informed of his rights prior to interrogation if said interrogation produces information used as trial evidence.

Comment: @DVK - No more chat ask it as a question if you want I am not explaining it to you here.  I do not think you should be adding this information to someone elses answer especially since I am pretty sure it is wrong.

Comment: *Note that the court very explicitly created a well-defined civil liberty (being informed of your rights prior to interrogation) where one didn't practically exist before, by interpreting existing law.* - This needs to be cited or removed.

Comment: The same sex marriage was a ruling that a protected right was being violated.  Not that a new right was created.

Comment: @Chad, you are confusing "civil right" and "civil liberty" with the same sex marriage info (but so is DVK). The same sex marriage case is a matter of discrimination, and equal protection under the law, and therefore a civil-rights issue (not that i agree with SCOTUS on this matter, but it is their ruling). I suppose you could also interpret that the court is stating that you have the liberty to marry whom you want (which wasn't the ruling ti my knowledge, SSM is still illegal in many states).

Comment: @user1873 - All that ruling did was say that the Federal government can not refuse to recognize same sex couples that are legally married in their state or deny them benfits they would offer to traditional wed couples.  It did not mandate that states allow same sex marriage.

Comment: @Chad, then I am confused at what point you were making with your comment, "The same sex marriage was a ruling that **a protected right** was being violated," and DVK's bolded quote, "denying same-sex couples the fundamental right to marry." Justice Walker and you are claiming that there is a fundamental "right to marry", where is that civil liberty defined in the constitution?

Comment: @User1873- I was really trying to avoid having this chat here in comments.

Answer (score -2):

The Declaration of Independence makes it pretty clear that the United States of America was founded upon the idea of rights being something that are not granted by a government bureaucracy but something that is a gift from god that each person is born with.

> When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.

Also

> We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness.

And the ninth amendment to the US constitution

> The enumeration in the Constitution, of certain rights, shall not be construed to deny or disparage others retained by the people.

So i don't think the supreme court or any branch of the government has the authority to define the rights of the people.

Comment: In theory, it does not, in practice, being charged with interpreting the constitution and having almost unlimited freedom in doing so, it does.